# Performance implications when shanging Private Sub to Public Sub in MS Access 2003 forms

Tags: ms-access-2003

The company I work for has a huge legacy MS Access 2003 application which I am now maintaining.  It is (very) slowly being migrated to .NET but with 200 forms, 150 classes / modules and 500 queries this won't be happening soon (think if it isn't broke don't fix it). Because the migration to .NET is happening I need to implement automated testing (including UI) and have built my own framework which works really well. But one feature requires that the form control events (eg. AfterUpdate) be changed from "Private Sub" to "Sub" to make public so that they can be called using CallByName.

Does anyone see a problem with doing a mass removal of "Private"?  Will performance be affected?  Considering this is a big MS Access app used by 1000's of users I don't want to screw it up.

To pre-empt the obvious question: There is plenty of business logic in the form code and refactoring is too big a task, so using something like RubberDuck is out of the question.

My question is really about what impact changing 1000's of "Private Sub" to "Public Sub" will have on the performance and memory usage of the database.

Comment: It shouldn't have any performance or memory impact. Maintainability may or may not be affected though.